# Curl OPTIONS request in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, curl, option

I would like to do this request :

```
curl -i -X OPTIONS my/url/path
```

in Magento 2.

This code works :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'my/url/path',
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'OPTIONS',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_NOBODY => true,
    CURLOPT_VERBOSE => true,
));
$r = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($r);
curl_close($ch);
```

But it's ugly code. I would like use dependency injection to clean my code.

Something like :

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl
 */
protected $_curl;

/**
 * @param Context                             $context
 * @param \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
 */
public function __construct(
    Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl $curl
) {
    $this->_curl = $curl;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    //if the method is get
    $this->_curl->get($url);
    //if the method is post
    $this->_curl->post($url, $params);
    //response will contain the output in form of JSON string
    $response = $this->_curl->getBody();
}
```

But there is no OPTIONS method. So do you have any idea how to do?

Comment: options method means what?

Comment: OPTIONS is a method like POST or GET are : https://daniel.haxx.se/blog/2017/06/19/options-with-curl/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I've not actually tried this, so I'm mainly going based off an initial look over the code.

I guess you have 2 options, extend or *workaround*:

You could extend the Curl client class and use your own class from it. Then you'd be able to make your own options method that does something like `$this->makeRequest("OPTIONS", $uri);` to call the parent's makeRequest method. Instead of bringing in the Magento Curl client via DI, you'd just bring in your own.

Second option:
Magento allows you to set `_curlUserOptions` values with a public method `setOption($name, $value)` on the curl client object. In the `makeRequest($method, $uri, $params = [])` method, these are set *after* the GET/POST options. I guess it could be possible that you can unset the `CURLOPT_HTTPGET` option for a get request and set your own `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` there.
Have a read through the file at `vendor/magento/framework/HTTP/Client/Curl.php` and look for the method `makeRequest` to see what it's doing properly.

Personally I'd make my own class extending the client but that's just me.

Comment: Thank you for your propostions. I'll try this if there is no other option

Comment: @Kozame let me know which you go for, I'd like to know if it works as predicted myself. Good luck

Comment: I use your first solution : $this->makeRequest("OPTIONS", $uri); It's work well ! :)